# Верстка в Joomla

Tags: joomla, cms

Как узнать в каких файлах находится верстка файла и по какому расположению в Joomla, чтобы, например, изменить часть макета, как, например, показано на фотке http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2017/02/24/0002/2779/191195/95/693705ccea.png страницы одного сайта на Joomla http://dallat.ru/chip? Может есть другие способы изменить верстку сайта на Joomla?

Answer (score 0):

т.к вы используйте компонент `com_onepage` для изменения стилей в корзине вам надо внести изменения в файле `openpage.css` который находится в 
 `components/com_onepage/themes/clean_simple/onepage.css`